# Updating a list in a Python class

Tags: python, list, class

I want to update a list to include new items added by a user. There are a few conditions such as the code must be 7 digits long. If the code already exists, the system will notify the user. If the user tries to add another copy of 'up' with a different code, the system will not allow it. It will make them try again as the code must be the same. Eventually I will include a video number, so if there are two copies of 'up' they will have two different video numbers but the same video code.

Can someone show me why the following code is not working for me?

```
all_movies = []

class Movie(object):
    movie_list = []


    def __init__(self, code, title, director):
        self.code = code
        self.title = title
        self.director = director

        Movie.movie_list.append(self)

    @staticmethod
    def add_movie():

        mv_code = input("Code of movie: ")
        movie_code = int(mv_code)
        movie_title = input("Name of movie: ")
        movie_director = input("Director: ")

        if len(mv_code) == 7:
           all_movies.append(Movie(movie_code, movie_title, movie_director))

           print("movie added to database")
        else:
            print("the code must be 7 digits long, add movie again.")

        def check_validity(movie_code, all_movies):
            if movie_code in all_movies:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        if check_validity(movie_code, all_movies):
            all_movies[all_movies] += Movie
            print()
            print("updated")
        else:
            all_movies[movie_code] = [movie_code, movie_title, movie_director]

def main():
    movie1 = Movie(1122334, 'Up', 'Director')
    movie2 = Movie(1231235, 'Taxi Driver', 'Film-maker')
```

This is the error message that I am receiving:

```
all_movies[movie_code] = [movie_code, movie_title, movie_director] 
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Not working how? What is not happening that is supposed to be? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman so sorry for not including the error message that iam recieving. here it is:

        all_movies[movie_code] = [movie_code, movie_title, movie_director]
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: If you have additional information, please edit your question. You can't format code/error messages in the comments and people often don't read comments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this structure is not suitable for your desires. 
About the error you got, I should say that you have to define you all movies as a dictionary not a list (because of the that you want to use for each movie). 
try this:

```
all_movies = {}
```

in you `add_movie` method:

```
@staticmethod
def add_movie():

    mv_code = input("Code of movie: ")
    movie_code = int(mv_code)
    movie_title = input("Name of movie: ")
    movie_director = input("Director: ")

    if len(mv_code) == 7:
       if movie_code in all_movies.keys():
           print("the movie already exists")
           # what do you want to happen here ? 
       else:
           all_movies[movie_code] = (movie_code, movie_title, movie_director)
           print("movie added to database")
    else:
        print("the code must be 7 digits long, add movie again.")
```

This will add a movie to the `all_movies` and you don't need the rest your code, and i didn't understand the usage of `init` and `movie_list`.

Try this, then tell me what happens if the code already exists in the movies, I will update my answer for you.

### UPDATE:

According to your desires in comment the method will updated to something like this:

```
@staticmethod
def add_movie():

    mv_code = input("Code of movie: ")
    movie_code = int(mv_code)
    movie_title = input("Name of movie: ")
    movie_director = input("Director: ")

    if len(mv_code) == 7:
       if movie_code in all_movies.keys():
           print("the movie is already exists, adding it with another video number")
           # all_movies[movie_code][-1] is the last video with an existing key
           # all_movies[movie_code][-1][-1] last video number generated
           new_video_number = all_movies[movie_code][-1][-1] + 1
           all_movies[movie_code].append([movie_title, movie_director, new_video_number]) # adding it with new video number
           print("movie added to database with new video number")        
       else:
           all_movies[movie_code] = []
           all_movies[movie_code].append([movie_title, movie_director, 1]) # 1 is the first movie added(video number)
           print("movie added to database")
    else:
        print("the code must be 7 digits long, add movie again.")
```

This will returns `all_movies` like this:

```
{
    '1231235':[
        ['Taxi Driver', 'Film-maker', 1]
    ]
    '1122334':[
        ['Up', 'Director',1],
        ['Up', 'Director',2],
        ['Up', 'Director',3],
   ]
    '1122333':[
        ['Another movie', 'Another Director',1],
        ['Another movie', 'Another Director',2],
   ]
}
```

The last element of inner list are the `video_numbers` that generated automatically by system.

Comment: thank you for your assistance. i am using classes for this project so i must keep the init. the movie_list was being used to store additional information if you needed. I will implement the changes and see what happens. 

Is there anyway to do this by keeping the information in a list or would dictionary just make it a lot easier?

Comment: @user9666493 you can also use list, but the fact that you need to access each movie by its code will guide you to use a dict for your store process.

Comment: thank you for your help again. I just want to give you a bit more background, this is part of a much bigger project that I am working on. I want the outcome to be as follows: 

Video Number:1
Video Code: 1231234
Title: Up
Director: Disney 

When a new one is added using the code above, it must recognise that the code is the same and give the new Video the next available number eg: 2. It must not allow the title or director to be different if the video code is the same. 

Video Number:2
Video Code: 1231234
Title: Up
Director: Disney

Comment: @user9666493 I am working on it. I will notify you when its ready.